# Elegant Rails: multiple routes, same controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the most elegant way to have multiple routes go to the same
controller action?

I have:

```
  get 'dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index'
  get 'dashboard/pending', to: 'dashboard#index'
  get 'dashboard/live', to: 'dashboard#index'
  get 'dashboard/sold', to: 'dashboard#index'
```

This is quite ugly. Any "more elegant" recommendations?
Bonus points for a one liner.

Comment: why do you want multiple routes going to the same controller action?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not have just one route and one controller action, and differ the functionality based on params passed to it?

#### config/routes.rb:

```
get 'dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index'
```

#### app/controller/dashboard_controller.rb

```
def index
  ...
  if params[:pending]
     # pending related stuff
  end
  if params[:live] 
    # live related stuff
  end
  if params[:sold] 
    # sold related stuff
  end     
  ...
end
```

#### links in views

- pending: `<%= link_to "Pending", dashboard_path(pending: true) %>`
- live: `<%= link_to "Live", dashboard_path(live: true) %>`
- sold: `<%= link_to "Sold", dashboard_path(sold: true) %>`

Comment: if on Rails 4.1+ you could also make use of variants to keep your templates orderly, i.e. index.html+live.erb http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#action-pack-variants

Comment: Thanks for that; I did not know about the variants concept.

Comment: I would recommend against this. Different functionality based on params is an antipattern. I think a better solution would be to define different actions for each route; and even more restul would be to create different controllers for each of your  'subactions'

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like these but reading some comments maybe is misleading or an antipattern.

In **config/routes.rb:**

`get 'dashboard/:action_name' => 'dashboard#index'`

Then in **app/controller/dashboard_controller.rb:**

```
def index
    ...
    action_name = request.original_url.split('/').last
    case action_name
    when "pending"
      # pending related stuff
    when "live"
      # live related stuff
    when "sold"
      # solde related stuff
    else
      # else related stuff
    end
    ...
end
```

The only problem here is that i do not know how to fit your first option **(with out an action name)** in this solution.

Hope it works for you.