# ElegantRails - Multiple Routes to one Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm wondering if there is a more cleaner or elegant way of translating multiple routes to one controller action using Rails.

```
#routes.rb

get 'suggestions/proxy', to: 'suggestions#index'
get 'suggestions/aimee', to: 'suggestions#index'
get 'suggestions/arty', to: 'suggestions#index'
...

#suggestion_controller.rb

case request.env['PATH_INFO']
when '/suggestions/proxy'
    @suggestions = Suggestion.all.where(:suggestion_type => 'proxy')
when '/suggestions/aimee'
    @suggestions = Suggestion.all.where(:suggestion_type => 'aimee')
when '/suggestions/arty'
    @suggestions = Suggestion.all.where(:suggestion_type => 'arty')
...
else
    @suggestions = Suggestion.all
end
```

I've read this this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174836/elegant-rails-multiple-routes-same-controller-action), but I kept getting errors when using it.

It's not a big deal if there's not a lot to be done here. I'm building a website on a video game I like playing called *Dirty Bomb* and there is a total of 19 mercenaries that need to be listed, so that's why I wanted a more cleaner way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: You should read up on [wildcard segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments). It's exactly for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely there is. You can use a parameter directly in your route. Even further, you can then use that parameter directly in your query, rather than using a case statement.

```html
#routes.rb

get 'suggestions/:type', to: 'suggestions#index'

# suggestions_controller.rb

def index
   @suggestions = Suggestion.where(suggestion_type: params[:type])
end
```

It's always a better practice to base your controller actions after parameters, rather than doing any interpretation of the path or request objects.

Hope it works!

Comment: Hi Rob, cool! No need to use 'all' in your query. Make the test: Suggestion.all.where(suggestion_type: params[:type]).to_sql and  Suggestion.where(suggestion_type: params[:type]).to_sql generate the same SQL statement

Comment: Ah! Yep, was doing a little bit of copy/paste there and forgot to remove the .all. Absolutely right.