# Rails - link_to going to index action instead of show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have no idea what's going on, but when I press my button to show a post, it redirects to the *index* action instead of *show*.

```
#suggestions_controller.rb

def show
    @suggestion = Suggestion.find(params[:id])
end

#index.html.erb

<% @suggestions.each do |suggestion| %>
... #other code
<li><%= link_to 'Comments', suggestion_path(suggestion), id: 'comments' %></li>
<% end %>
```

Routes:
[image: These are my routes]

[image: Going to index route]

Every time I press my *Comments* button, it redirects to index. My head is spinning why this is happening. I'm 100% sure that `suggestion_path(suggestion)` (in terms of my routes) is the correct path for the `show` action.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: show routes.rb file and full controller code with full view where link is being hit.

Answer (score 0):

the link_ is correct, it points to the route you want, but it does not correspond to the call you receive on the server, there comes a parameter type => 3 which does not make any sense, for me you must press the wrong link

it's as if instead of having suggestion_path (suggestion) you point to suggestions_path (suggestion) with s and send as a type a parameter => 3

Check the link_to of your app

Answer (score -1):

I had an epiphany that it was a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193956/elegantrails-multiple-routes-to-one-controller-action) I had recently made on StackOverflow just a few days ago.

I changed the route to

```
#routes.rb

get 'suggestions/:type', to: 'suggestions#index'

#suggestion_controller.rb

if params[:type].nil?
    @suggestions = Suggestion.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)
else
    @suggestions = Suggestion.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).where(:suggestion_type => params[:type])
end
```

to fetch all my 19 mercenaries in a more elegant way.

This works perfectly, but when I click on *Comments* to show the specific suggestion, it routes automatically to `suggestions/:type` which directs to the *index* action. The whole purpose of this was to filter my database every time a specific mercenary was clicked.

To fix the issue, I reverted back to my long version:

```
#routes.rb

get 'suggestions/proxy', to: 'suggestions#index'
get 'suggestions/aimee', to: 'suggestions#index'
get 'suggestions/arty', to: 'suggestions#index'
...

#suggestion_controller.rb

case request.env['PATH_INFO']
when '/suggestions/proxy'
    @suggestions = Suggestion.all.where(:suggestion_type => 'proxy')
when '/suggestions/aimee'
    @suggestions = Suggestion.all.where(:suggestion_type => 'aimee')
when '/suggestions/arty'
    @suggestions = Suggestion.all.where(:suggestion_type => 'arty')
...
else
    @suggestions = Suggestion.all
end
```

and now my button goes to the *show* action as intended.

As much as I hate this version, I struggle to find any other elegant way of structuring my routing in a more effective way.